# python String Pattern Matching

Tags: python

two string expression： `@RequestMapping(value = "/list/base/info")` or `@RequestMapping("/list/base/info")`

How do I get uri `/list/base/info` value by String Pattern Matching?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and show your own effort. As a first hint, have a look at regular expressions and the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re).

Comment: `print "/list/base/info"`

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can try getting it by split:

```
expression.split("\"")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

re.match(
    '@RequestMapping\((value\s*=\s*)?"([^"]+)"\)',
    '@RequestMapping(value = "/list/base/info")'
).group(2)
```

That would output:

```
'/list/base/info'
```